# Conditional jump not working (AT&T Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, conditional-statements, att

I'm currently learning about AT&T Assembly, and i'm having a problem with conditional jump. Here's what i'm doing

```
.section .data
msg_less:
    .string "Less than 65"
msg_greaterequal:
    .string "Greater than or equal to 65"
.section .bss:
    .lcomm input, 2
.section .text
    .globl _start

_start:
    #Input a char
    movl $3, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $input, %ecx
    movl $2, %edx
    int $0x80

    #Output the previous char
    subl $1, (input)
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $input, %ecx
    movl $2, %edx
    int $0x80

    #Check if the numeric value of the input char is less / greater than or equal to 65 
    #If input < 65
    cmpl $65, (input)
    jl .L_less
    #Else: input >= 65
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $msg_greaterequal, %ecx
    movl $28, %edx
    int $0x80
    jmp .L_End

.L_less:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $msg_less, %ecx
    movl $13, %edx
    int $0x80
#End
.L_End:
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

The "Input" and "Print previous char" worked correctly, but the "Check if" always jumps to "Greater than or equal to 65" case regardless of the input

[image: Screenshot of result while running]

And if i change jl to jge the result will always jump to "Less than 65" case.
I don't know what caused this, and how to fix this?

Comment: `cmpl $65, (input)` is a 4-byte compare, of 4 bytes including the newline you read, as well as 2 bytes past the end of the space you reserved in the BSS (which are probably zero).  Use `cmpb` if you want to compare a byte.

Comment: General advice: do not develop software as root unless you know exactly what you are doing.  This is fairly dangerous to do.